# Why use toString() to typecheck args that you can check with typeof?

Tags: javascript, types, typechecking

I understand why you need to use `Object.prototype.toString()` or `String()` for typechecking arrays, but isn't [typeof](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js) sufficient for typechecking functions and strings? For example the polyfill on MDN for [Array.isArray](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js) uses:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(arg) == '[object Array]';
```

It's pretty clear in the case of arrays because you can't use `typeof` to check for arrays. [Valentine](https://github.com/ded/valentine/blob/master/valentine.js) uses [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) for this:

```
ar instanceof Array
```

But for strings/functions/booleans/numbers, why not use `typeof`?

[jQuery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js) and [Underscore](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js) both use something like this to check for functions:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) == '[object Function]';
```

Isn't that equivalent to doing this?

```
typeof obj === 'function'
```

or even this?

```
obj instanceof Function
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ok I think I figured out why you see the `toString` usage. Consider this:

```
var toString = Object.prototype.toString;
var strLit = 'example';
var strStr = String('example')​;
var strObj = new String('example');

console.log(typeof strLit); // string    
console.log(typeof strStr); // string
console.log(typeof strObj); // object

console.log(strLit instanceof String); // false
console.log(strStr instanceof String); // false
console.log(strObj instanceof String); // true

console.log(toString.call(strLit)); // [object String]
console.log(toString.call(strStr)); // [object String]
console.log(toString.call(strObj)); // [object String]
```

​

Comment: Do note that it does not work with Promises, at least in Chrome in Firefox. `typeof mypromise === 'object`, `toString.call(mypromise) === '[Object]'`, but `mypromise instanceof Promise === true`

Comment: @Hurelu  That makes sense because `Promise` inherits from `Object`. I get `"[object Object]"` using `.call` but if you do `promise.toString` it gives `"[object Promise]"`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/27746304/770127

Answer (score 1):

The first reason I can think of is that `typeof null` returns `object`, which is not usually what you want (since `null` is not an object, but a type in its own right).

However, `Object.prototype.toString.call(null)` returns `[object Null]`.

But, as you suggest, if you expect something to be a string or other type that works well with `typeof`, I see no reason why you can't use `typeof` (and I regularly do use `typeof` in that case).

Another reason libraries such as those you mention use their chosen method may simply be for consistency. You can use `typeof` to check for an `Array`, so use another method and stick to that throughout.

For some more information, [Angus Croll has an excellent article on the `typeof` operator](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/08/08/fixing-the-javascript-typeof-operator/).

Comment: I'm talking about checking stuff the seemingly should work without a hitch like strings/functions/booleans/numbers

Comment: Do note that it does not work with Promises, at least in Chrome in firefox. `typeof mypromise === 'object`, `toString.call(mypromise) === '[Object]'`, but `mypromise instanceof Promise === true`

Comment: @Hurelu - In latest stable Chrome I get `"[object Promise]"` for `Object.prototype.toString.call(mypromise)`

Comment: Funny. Just upgraded to Chrome 43.0.2357.81 and I still get `[object Object]`. I only checked through the console. I also checked again in Firefox and [object Promise] now comes correctly. Because of these mixed results, I would still caution against this method for detecting promises reliably.