# Test that returned value is a promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, angular-promise

Given angular controller with function

```
this.checkResponse = function (response) {
  if (response.success === true) {
    return $q.resolve(response);
  } else {
    return $q.reject(response);
  }
};
```

how do I test with Jasmine that returned value is a promise? I can easily verify that I called resolve or reject inside a function, or that I receive jasmine.any(Function), but how do I ensure that it's a promise?

Comment: You might want to look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27746304/how-do-i-tell-if-an-object-is-a-promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do like this in my tests:

```
//done callback will ensure that success function should called
it('blabla', function(done){
    //when 
    app.checkResponse().then(function(){
        done();
    }, function(){
        fail("error callback has been called");
        done();
    });
})
```

It will ensure that you have to return with a promise, otherwise it'll fail with timeout. For me this is the quickest solution.

Is that what you are looking for? Or did I misunderstood you?

Comment: Yes, it looks like what I might need and I also though of a similar approach, but for some reason I was sure that there might be something more elegant.

Comment: I use this approach in my project. I don't know any more elegant solution.