# How can code that might run under NodeJS, JXcore, etc detect whether it's running in an environment that supports native ES6 promises?

Tags: node.js, promise, feature-detection, es6-promise, jxcore

For example, I have pretty current versions of official Joyent NodeJS installed with of course the Google V8 JavaScript engine and also JXcore with the Mozilla SpiderMonkey JavaScript engine.

The former seems to come with native Promises support, the latter seems not to.

(And of course these are not the only two possible environments nodeJS code might run under.

How can my code test its environment to see whether it can use native Promises or not?

It's OK if it detects a proper polyfill as "native" in this case. But it shouldn't detect something like Q as native promises. (Or let me know if I'm wrong about this.)

Answer (score 2):

To directly answer your question, use this to detect the availability of ES6 promises:

```
typeof global.Promise === 'function'
```

Alternatively use a [lightweight ES6 promise polyfill](https://github.com/taylorhakes/promise-polyfill) instead of relying on a larger partially-incompatible library.

With a polyfill you can just use the normal Promise API and simply remove the `require` once it's no longer needed — no refactor necessary.

---

A longer but trustworthier alternative is something like what this [package uses](https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise/blob/master/lib/es6-promise/polyfill.js):

```
  global.Promise && Object.prototype.toString.call(global.Promise.resolve()) === '[object Promise]')
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use a [package](https://github.com/normalize/native-or-bluebird) that uses native promises if they're available and if they're not it shims them.

Alternatively, since it's the server, you might be better off using a [compatible userland library](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) until all your environments support native promises.

Note that jxcore does not support some standard NodeJS promise features like `unhandledRejection` that userland polyfills and libraries support.

As for detecting native promises - it can be hard across environments. Technically you could check if there is a global `Promise` object as the first line of code in your program but that's messy compared to the alternative of just using a compatible faster userland library.

Answer (score 1):

This might do it:

```
Promise.resolve() instanceof Promise
```

From [comments to this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28133130/918910), it seems this only returns true for native ES6 promises.

This solution would likely reject a polyfill however.