# Notification.requestPermission throws an error in Mac versions of Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari, web-notifications

I am trying to display notifications with jQuery locally on page load. The notification is showing correctly in Firefox, Firefox Developer, and Chrome. The notification is not appearing in Safari despite allowed in notification preference settings.

Similar code is working from MDN site https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/notification.

Snippet is below.

```
// Display a sample notification
  if (window.Notification) {
    return $(".au-notifications-page").show(function() {
      var notification;
      notification = new Notification(
        'Success Text', {
        //tag: $("[name=tag]").val(),
        body: 'Success Message',
        iconUrl: 'img/avatar-male.png',
        icon: 'img/avatar-male.png'
      });
      return notification.onclick = function() {
        notification.close();
        window.open().close();
        return window.focus();
      };
    });
  };
```

Complete code is below.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  // Request permission on site load
  Notification.requestPermission().then(function(result) {
    if (result === 'denied') {
      //alert('denied');
      $(".au-notif-disabled-header").removeClass('hide');
      $(".au-notif-disabled-header .btn").addClass('hide');
      return;
    }
    if (result === 'default') {
      //alert('ignored');
      $(".au-notif-disabled-header").removeClass('hide');
      return;
    }
    //alert('granted');
    $(".au-notif-disabled-header").addClass('hide');
  });

  // Request permission with button
  $('.au-notif-disabled-header .btn').click(function () {
    Notification.requestPermission().then(function(result) {
      if (result === 'denied') {
        $(".au-notif-disabled-header").removeClass('hide');
        $(".au-notif-disabled-header .btn").addClass('hide');
        return;
      }
      if (result === 'default') {
        $(".au-notif-disabled-header").removeClass('hide');
        return;
      }
      $(".au-notif-disabled-header").addClass('hide');
    });
  });

  $( ".au-notification-icon" ).hover(
    function() {
      $(".au-notifications-menu .au-notif-msg-realtime").slideDown();
      $('.au-notification-icon .badge').html("2");
    }, function() {
      $(".au-notifications-menu .au-notif-msg-realtime").slideUp();
      $('.au-notification-icon .badge').html("1");
    }
  );

  //To show notification received while on notifications page
  $(".au-notif-msg-realtime").hide();
  //$(".au-notifications-page .au-notif-msg-realtime").slideDown();

  $(".au-notifications-page .au-notif-msg-realtime").slideDown({
    complete: function(){
      $('.au-notification-icon .badge').html("2");
      $('head title').html("(2) Notifications");
    }
  });


  // Display a sample notification
  if (window.Notification) {
    return $(".au-notifications-page").show(function() {
      var notification;
      notification = new Notification(
        'Success Heading', {
          body: 'Success Text',
          iconUrl: 'img/avatar-male.png',
          icon: 'img/avatar-male.png'
      });
      return notification.onclick = function() {
        notification.close();
        window.open().close();
        return window.focus();
      };
    });
  };
});
```

EDIT 1: Safari throws this exception

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Notification.requestPermission().then')

Answer (score 20):

You have to use a callback function for Safari, since it doesn't return a Promise.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API):

> This uses the promise-version of the method, as supported in recent
>   implementations (Firefox 47, for example.) If you want to support
>   older versions, you might have to use the older callback version,
>   which looks like this:

Here's the sample code they gave:

```
Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
    // If the user accepts, let's create a notification
    if (permission === "granted") {
        var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
    }
});
```

To support Safari notifications, this is what I ended up with:

```
    try {
        Notification.requestPermission()
            .then(() => doSomething())                                                                                                                                               
    } catch (error) {
        // Safari doesn't return a promise for requestPermissions and it                                                                                                                                       
        // throws a TypeError. It takes a callback as the first argument                                                                                                                                       
        // instead.
        if (error instanceof TypeError) {
            Notification.requestPermission(() => {                                                                                                                                                             
                doSomething();
            });
        } else {
            throw error;                                                                                                                                                                                       
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    }
```

Comment: As some browsers (i.e. Safari on iOS 11.4) don't support `Notification` it might be a good practice to check `typeof Notification !== 'undefined'` before executing the try/catch block.

Answer (score 13):

A better solution is to wrap the results in a `Promise` and *then* (no pun intended) run your code. This code works on all browsers (including Safari) and without a complicated `if` block (concept is discussed in detail in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27746304/2370483))

```
Promise.resolve(Notification.requestPermission()).then(function(permission) {
    // Do something
});
```

This works because `Promise.resolve` does nothing to a `Promise`, but will convert the Safari `requestPermission()` to a `Promise`.

Note that iOS Safari still does not support the Notification API so you will need to [check if it is available first](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38422340/2370483)

Comment: On safari, permission will be undefined on Safari, right?

Comment: `permission` is merely the argument name I picked. The promise will pass the notification permission object to the callback function

Comment: This doesn't work, because `Notification.requestPermission()` immediately returns `undefined` on Safari,  the `then` function will be called instantly, without waiting for the permission request dialog to be resolved, and regardless of what the user chooses.

Answer (score 1):

To return a promise which doesn't resolve until the user grants or denies permission to show notifications:

```
        if (!permissionPromise && Notification.permission === 'granted' ) {
            permissionPromise = Promise.resolve(Notification.permission);
        }
        if (!permissionPromise) {
            permissionPromise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                // Safari uses callback, everything else uses a promise
                var maybePromise = $window.Notification.requestPermission(resolve, reject);
                if (maybePromise && maybePromise.then) {
                    resolve(maybePromise);
                }
            });
        }
        return permissionPromise;
```

Answer (score 0):

Modern solution for outdated problem:

```
new Promise((resolve) => {
   Notification.requestPermission(resolve)?.then(resolve);
}).then(permission => console.log(permission))
```

Safari accepts only first callback and ignores `?.then(...)`. Chrome and FF will likely resolve promise twice, but it won't matter.

Unlike most voted answer, this one does not request permissions twice, which opens 2 permission popups in my Safari v13.1.2.

Answer (score 0):

```
async function requestPermission() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {

    const timeoutId = setInterval(() => {
      if (Notification.permission === 'granted') {
        handleComplete(Notification.permission);
      }
    }, 3000);

    const handleComplete = (permission) => {
      clearInterval(timeoutId);
      resolve(permission);
    };

    Notification.requestPermission(handleComplete)?.then?.(handleComplete);
  });
}
```