# Check if browser notification is available

Tags: javascript, browser, notifications

I am working with browser notifications and because it is not available for every browser I want to check in my *JS-code*, if it is available.

I took a look in the Mozilla developer section:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API

They tell me that I should use this code to check whether a browser has notification support or not:

```
  if (!("Notification" in window)) {
    alert("This browser does not support system notifications");
  }
```

I copied that code into my website; the notification still works in the browsers where it worked before but it blocks the execution of other code (as it did before the 'check'-code).

For example: in the edge browser, I get the console error:

> ```
>  'Notification is undefined'
> ```

So what is the preferred method from you to check whether a browser has notification capability?

Comment: If `("Notification" in window)` is `false`, then your code has to avoid using any of the APIs.

Comment: Sorry, my fault! I have to check that twice in my code and i missed one.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The following code would check whether the browser is compatible with the web notification API

```
if ('Notification' in window) {
  // API supported
} else {
  // API not supported
}
```

Comment: @JeroenVannevel the code is checking if the global `window` object has `Notification` as a property on it. If it does, then the current  browser does support the Notification API.

Answer (score 6):

You should also check for the prefixed versions:

```
var NotificationIsSupported = !!(window.Notification /* W3C Specification */ || window.webkitNotifications /* old WebKit Browsers */ || navigator.mozNotification /* Firefox for Android and Firefox OS */)
```

You can read more on how to do this in [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20170302194725/https://justmarkup.com/log/2013/09/notification-api/). The article also has a lot of code examples of how to support other devices.