# chai how to check that function returns a promise

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sinon, chai

I'm using sinon / chai and some other plugins, I can test promises and their results, etc, but how can I ensure that a function returns a promsie?

I realize that if other tests pass (eg. when you run the rest with return or await and get expected result) it means it is a promise, but is there something along the lines of:

```
expect(foo).to.return.a('promise')
```

**EDIT:** Unfortunately the suggested post did NOT answer my question with unit testing, but I did figure out the answer:

```
let result = foo();
expect(result).to.be.a('promise');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I tell if an object is a Promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27746304/how-do-i-tell-if-an-object-is-a-promise)

Comment: @laggingreflex this isn't a duplicate, the question is specifically about how you do this using chai

Comment: @mankind I suggest you post your solution as an answer rather than edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

```js
expect(result instanceof Promise).to.be.eql(true)
```