# await with overloaded methods

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await

I have an ES6 class hierarchy. All of the classes in the hierarchy implement a `draw()` method. Some implement it synchronously but some need this method to be `async`.
How can I call `draw()` correctly in this sort of setup?
Is it possible to find if the method being called is `async` and only then call `await` on it's result?

Comment: You need to be consistent whether draw will return a promise or not.

Comment: I wanted to avoid having to declate 100 methods as async for the sake of just the two that actually need it

Comment: How about this? `draw.constructor.name == 'AsyncFunction'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wanted to avoid having to decla(r)e 100 methods as async for the
>   sake of just the two that actually need it.

A function doesn't have to be `async` (ie: return a promise) to be `await`ed. A synchronous function can be awaited too. This means that if a promise is not returned by `draw()` (ie: your draw() method is synchronous), then the `await` will convert the returned value of `draw()` to a resolved promise which it then waits for and retrieves its value.

So, something like the following is possible:

```js
function foo() { // returns a string
  return "foo";
}

async function bar() { // implicitly returns a promise
  return "bar"; 
}

(async function() {
  const fooStr = await foo(); // foo() is synchronous, but can be `await`ed still
  const barStr = await bar(); // bar() is asynchronous, and can be `await`ed
  console.log(fooStr, barStr);
})();
```

With this in mind, you don't need to know if `draw()` is synchronous or not, instead, you can always `await` the `draw()` method, regardless of its return type.

Answer (score 3):

You could check if the draw() has a `.then` function since all promises will have to implement that. If it does, use async, else execute directly

Check this answer on how to determine a promise [How do I tell if an object is a Promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27746304/how-do-i-tell-if-an-object-is-a-promise)

```
  if(draw.then) {  // all async await functions wrap the return into promises. So, this should 
    const resolvedData = await draw(); // store the data if you need to get the value
  else
    draw()
```

Comment: Is the function itself a `Promise` or is it's return value a `Promise` ?

Comment: This seem to be wrong. The async function doesn't have `then`

Comment: @shoosh I'm not the original answerer, but you'll need to call `.then()` on the _return_, not the `draw` function itself. All `async` functions will implicitly return a promise, and so I imagine this will work.

Comment: @NickParsons that seems like the best answer

Comment: But I assume the draw to be a variable storing the async function, so, it should have draw().then for it to be used as a promise ?

Answer (score 1):

You can check your function if it is async function by using `Object.prototype.constructor.name`.

```js
var object = {
  draw: async function() {}
}
var object1 = {
  draw: function() {}
}

console.log(object.draw.constructor.name);
console.log(object1.draw.constructor.name);
```