# How can I set state in useMemo with an async function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to fetch data during `ComponentWillMount` lifecycle in server side using `useMemo()`

```js
  const [text, setText] = useState('hello')
  
  const fakeApiCall = new Promise(resolve => 'world')
  
  useMemo(async () => {
    const value = await fakeApiCall
    setText(value)
  }, [])
```

Doing this the value for `text` will still remain `hello` instead of `world`. Is it possible to achieve this? Why is this not working?

Comment: If I remember correct, for a given pair of dependencies, `useMemo` returns a value. So ideally, you should pass dependencies. Also, `useMemo(() => {}, [])` is not `componentWillMount`. Try `useEffect(() => {}, [])` instead as API data should be fetched after component is mounted. Else, you can have lag in your component

Comment: `useMemo` is for memoizing a value, there should be ***zero*** side-effects. I think you are wanting to use the `useEffect` hook to initialize state. Also, for all practical purposes, `componentWillMount` is deprecated, use the equivalent of `componentDidMount`, which is `useEffect` with an empty dependency array.

Comment: @DrewReese But if I use `useEffect`, it would not be triggered in server side, and I cannot only fetch data in client side.

Comment: Right, it gets a little funky with react hooks, mounting, and SSR. A google search finds a bunch of work arounds.

Comment: In any case, you will need to put the `fakeApiCall` creation *inside* that hook, where you `await` the promise.

Answer (score 1):

as you know, the await will be return a 'promise object', and after the response came out it will be replaced with 'promise value', all you need is a falge to detect whenever you got a success response .

your code will seems like

```
  const [text, setText] = useState('hello')
  
  const fakeApiCall = new Promise(resolve => 'world')
  
  const [flage,setFlag] = useState(false) //adding whatever your flag name

  useMemo(async () => {
    const response = await fakeApiCall

    if(response.Success) // you will check on response result
    {
     setText(value)
    }
  }, [])
```

or you can check on this [Promise.resolve(valueOrPromiseItDoesntMatter).then](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27746304/how-do-i-tell-if-an-object-is-a-promise)

Answer (score 0):

Practically, you can achieve all you need here with `useState` and `useEffect`:

```js
  const [text, setText] = useState('hello')
  
  const fakeApiCall = new Promise(resolve => 'world')

  useEffect(() => {
    fakeApiCall()
      .then(response => { setText(response) })
  },[])
```

Note that you do not need to make the function within the `useEffect` hook async as it will resolve normally through typical promise flow.

As we have passed nothing into the dependency array, this hook will execute once on component mount and effectively memoise the response in the `text` variable.