# How to build function that works with or without promises

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to build a `sort` function that should be able to work with and without promises indistictevly.

The function fingerprint should be something like this:

```
function sort<T>(list: T[], fn: (item: T) => string | number): T[];
function sort<T>(list: Promise<T[]>, fn: (item: T) => string | number): Promise<T[]>;
```

So the idea is that I can use it regardless if `list` is or not a promise while the return type should match the input type.

I've done this kind of constructions with other types (like a map function for both arrays and objects) but promises present an additional challenge as I would need to declare the method as `async` in order to plus, doing so, it forces me to always return a promise.

How can I do this? Is this even possible?

Comment: How on earth did you find the solution right at the time you posted it? I mean seconds by seconds

Comment: After I got the question written down I started to think on why Typescript forces me to use Promise when declaring the function as `async` so I started playing with the code (still haven't submitted the question). Eventually I figured it out that without `async`, you can return whatever you want being a promise a valid return too.
I was about to remove the question but then I thought somebody else would benefit from it so I posted the answer. If it is not that useful, I can remove it. I certainly took me a lot of time to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, just figured it out myself. The solution it to take advantage from the fact that you can chain promises:

```
function sort<T>(list: T[], fn: (item: T) => string | number): T[];
function sort<T>(list: Promise<T[]>, fn: (item: T) => string | number): Promise<T[]>;
function sort<T>(list: Promise<T[]> | T[], fn: (item: T) => string | number): Promise<T[]> | T[] {
  const doPlainArraySort = (items: T[]): T[] => { /* Do your sorting algorithm here */ };

  if (list instanceof Promise) {
    return list.then(doPlainArraySort);
  }

  return doPlainArraySort(list);
}
```

The only problem to this approach is that checking for a promise [might not be trivial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27746304/how-do-i-tell-if-an-object-is-a-promise/27746324#27746324) but, otherwise, it works as expected!