# a function that executes any type of function

Tags: node.js, async-await, es6-promise

I want to know if there is a way to write a function that can execute any type of function whether it's async or not. I want to make sure to get the return value or if some error occurred while execution.

Comment: I think you'll have to give us a more concreate description of what you're trying to do.  You call a function the same whether it's asynchronous or not.  Extracting the return value from an asynchronous function depends entirely upon how the function is written.  It needs to either accept a callback that will be called upon completion or error or it needs to return a promise that will resolve with the final value upon success and reject upon error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27760489/457268

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have an object that contains properties that are functions. like a router for instance that executes handlers. I don't know what type of a function I'm getting but I don't want my app to crash if something goes wrong while executing. bear in mind that I'm not using express just vanilla JS. if there's a setTimeout in that function that throws an error I can't catch it even while wrapping the caller function in try/catch and my app crashes.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the function to an async function and have it wait for completion.

```
async function exec(myFunc, args = []) {
    return await myFunc(...args);
}
```

```
function myExampleAddFunction(a, b) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log('Hello');
        resolve(a + b);
  });
}

const result = await exec(myExampleAddFunction, [1, 2]);
```

`args` is an optional parameter where you can pass your function's arguments as an array.

This will work irrespective of whether the function returns a value or a promise.